# Scheduling an iFrame

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have what is best categorized as a general question that I have been unable to answer with my searches on the web. I'm trying to see if it is possible to program the src of an iframe to be active for a predetermined window of time, say for instance 3-4p (est) recurring weekly.

I am currently having to manually enter the src link each week, but want to know if there is a way to automate this.

Your insight is appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: Do you have control over the iframe? Maybe you can use `setTimeout('iframe.src=url',604800000);`

Comment: Yes, I do have control over the iframe. Your suggestion seems viable, i'll give it a try. This function would be called onLoad for the <body> right?

Comment: It is pseudocode ;) If you get your iframe in the onload function you need to set the time out after that.